# Whooshing sound after turning off tap

Tags: plumbing, water

I hope you all can provide some insight as to what might be causing a new Whooshing sound in my water system for about a second after I close any tap in my house.
It doesn't happen all the time and mostly, seems to come when I run the cold water for some time (Like when I fill the kettle).
I have drained the water system per directions found on the web and still get the whoosh intermittently.  Water pressure is great.  Same as always.

Nothing had been changed or modified in the plumbing system.  The only event that I could think of
is, about a month ago, the power was shut off by the local utility for about 6 hours to the whole neighbourhood for maintenance.  Could that have something to do with it?
I have a 10 year old electric water heater.  There are some copper and some plastic pipes in the system.  I used to get a bang sound when I turned the water in the kitchen off but don't now.
The house is 40 years old.
Thank you for your time and trouble.
I sure hope you can help.

Comment: Can you narrow the sound down to coming from  the water pipes or the drain pipes?  Drain pipes might lead to a vent problem.

Comment: Are there specific location(s) where you hear the sound? Those would be the first place(s) to look. Does the sound come from the tap? Does it come from the drain? Can you access supply/drain lines in the basement/utility room and hear it there?